# Loop backwards to find equal values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop

I am quite new to Python and am trying to do a quite simple loop to count how many equal values are before each row. Here is an example.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMZE0.png

Here is what I have tried, but can not seem to get it right.

```
df['count'] = 0       
count = 1

for i in df.index:
    if df['CD'].loc[i] == 'C':
        for j in range(count):
            if j<i:
                if df['CD'].loc[i] == df['CD'].df[i-j]:
                    df['count'].loc[i] = df['count'].loc[i] + 1
                    count = count + 1
                else:
                    count = 1
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
counts = []    

for i in df.index:
    count = 0
    while True:
        try:
            if df['CD'].loc[i-count] == C:
                count += 1
            else:
                break
        except:
            break
    if count == 0:
        counts.append(0)
    else:
        counts.append(count-1)
df["count"] = counts
```

Comment: Thanks John, that did the trick. When you add while True that means it will keep looping when the previous value is "C", right? Else it will break the loop and start for the next index. I just don't get the append part, what is it doing?

Comment: It is adding the number to a list that will create the column.

Comment: Thanks. What if I wanted to do it the other way around, by that I mean it counts how many are below instead of above?

Comment: Just change ```df.index``` into ```list(df.index).reverse()``` and ```df["count"] = counts``` into ```df["count"] = counts.reverse```

Comment: John, I managed to iterate using `list(reversed(df.index))` and `list(reversed(counts))` , but it gives me the same result as before. Don't I need to change something on the loop when I check the previous row?

I have tried to do change `if df['CD'].loc[i-count] == "C":` to `if df['CD'].loc[i+count] == "C":` but still no success.

Comment: My bad. How about this? ```if df['CD'].loc[i-count] == C:``` into ```if df['CD'].loc[i+count] == C:```

Comment: That works with a little adaptation on my loop to avoid having i+count be an index that does not exist.